# MongoDB $or for two fields inside $match stage

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here's a sample of my MongoDB documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59caa2660aaafa0016344ce0"),
    "field1" : true,
    "field2" : false
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59caa2690aaafa0016344ce1"),
    "field1" : false,
    "field2" : false
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59caa26c0aaafa0016344ce2"),
    "field1" : false,
    "field2" : true
}
```

How do I match all documents that have the value of `field1` **OR** the value of `field2` **OR** both `field1` and `field2` set to true?

In other words, I want to exclude documents where `field1` and `field2` both are false.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Not able to think of anything where I can ensure both fields are false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) with [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/index.html), try:

```
db.col.find({ $expr: { $or: [ "$field1", "$field2" ] } })
```

Comment: Cool mickl. +1 for the different approach... haven't  used key value pair with `$or` **:-)**

Comment: Great answer mickl. Works perfectly!